# Player is not changing between 'X' and 'O' in the program

Tags: c++

I want to create a game (connect four) in C++ using arrays and loops.

1. First I created a 8x5 board.
2. Second I am prompting the user to select the columns from 1 to 6.
3. When the user selects any one of columns, then the last row of that column will change from `'.'` to `'X'` or `'O'`.

Everything is working fine but the player is not shifting between `'X'` and `'O'` in `void TogglePlayer(&player)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int rows = 8;
const int columns = 5;
char player = 'X';
//This function creates a 8x5 board
char matrix[rows][columns] = { '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.',
                               '.','.','.','.','.' };

 //This function displays the board
void display()
{

    int width = 3;

    cout <<  setw(width) << "1" << setw(width) << "2" << setw(width) << "3" << 
    setw(width) << "4" << setw(width) << "5" << setw(width) << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(width) << "1" << setw(width) << "2" << setw(width) << "3" << setw(width) << "4" << setw(width) << "5" << setw(width) << '\n';
 }


  //This the main function that executes the player's selected column
void input(char player)
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the column" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 0 && a < 6)
    {
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][a - 1] == '.')
            {
                matrix[i][a - 1] = player;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}



//This function changes the players between 'X' or 'O'
void togglePlayer(char &player)
{
    if (player == 'O')
    {
        player = 'X';
    }
    else player = 'O';
}




int main()
{   
    while (true)
    {
        display();
        input(player);
        togglePlayer(player);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep staring at the following line: `for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i++)`, and keep staring it until you see your bug. After you see it, run a Google search for "undefined behavior".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik When I put a breakpoint on that `for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i++)` and executed my program is running fine but it is not going into the function `TogglePlayer` why?

Comment: Your `togglePlayer` function looks fine to me, btw.  Consider moving your `char player` declaration into main (just copy/paste that line) so that you have one less effectively global variable, and so that there's no confusion about global `char player` vs. togglePlayer's locally-scoped `char &player`

Comment: It takes a very long time to `++` a variable from 7 until it reaches 0. Especially if you debug your code one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments section of the question, the problem is with the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i++)
```

As you are comparing the value of `i` with `0` in the controlling expression, the value of `i` should decrease with every iteration.

Here is something that will help you avoid bugs in loops in the future. 
Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011712/what-are-your-tips-for-keeping-track-and-avoiding-bugs-in-loops) and its answers, especially this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015064/10190237).

Comment: The answer was already given in the comments and the OP found it. I did not want to repeat it again here. I wrote this information as an answer because most people don't read all the comments. But if you insist I can add the answer too.